# How to read \" double-quote escaped values with read.table in R

Tags: r, csv, escaping, double-quotes

I am having trouble to read a file containing lines like the one below in R.

```
"_:b5507F4C7x59005","Fabiana D\"atri"
```

Any idea? How can I make read.table understand that \" is the escape of quote?

Cheers,
Alexandre

Comment: I might be good to add a line or two extra in your sample so you don't get answers that only work for your single line...

Comment: See [How to read quoted text containing escaped quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032296/how-to-read-quoted-text-containing-escaped-quotes) for a solution in R using readLines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that `read.table/read.csv` **cannot handle** escaped quotes.

...But I think I have an (ugly) work-around inspired by @nullglob;

- First read the file WITHOUT a quote character. 
  (This won't handle embedded `,` as @Ben Bolker noted)
- Then go though the string columns and remove the quotes:

The test file looks like this (I added a non-string column for good measure):

```
13,"foo","Fab D\"atri","bar"
21,"foo2","Fab D\"atri2","bar2"
```

And here is the code:

```
# Generate test file
writeLines(c("13,\"foo\",\"Fab D\\\"atri\",\"bar\"",
             "21,\"foo2\",\"Fab D\\\"atri2\",\"bar2\"" ), "foo.txt")

# Read ignoring quotes
tbl <- read.table("foo.txt", as.is=TRUE, quote='', sep=',', header=FALSE, row.names=NULL)

# Go through and cleanup    
for (i in seq_len(NCOL(tbl))) {
    if (is.character(tbl[[i]])) {
        x <- tbl[[i]]
        x <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x)-1) # Remove surrounding quotes
        tbl[[i]] <- gsub('\\\\"', '"', x) # Unescape quotes
    }
}
```

The output is then correct:

```
> tbl
  V1   V2          V3   V4
1 13  foo  Fab D"atri  bar
2 21 foo2 Fab D"atri2 bar2
```

Comment: It seems to me more work than expected. But @Tommy solution works! Thanks!

Comment: What do you do if data contain the saparator character? You can't read without quotes or data will be split.

Comment: By now, this is not the best answer anymore ... the best answer is readr::read_delim(), now, see below.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux/Unix (or on Windows with cygwin or GnuWin32), you can use `sed` to convert the escaped double quotes `\"` to doubled double quotes `""` which can be handled well by `read.csv`:

```
p <- pipe(paste0('sed \'s/\\\\"/""/g\' "', FILENAME, '"'))
d <- read.csv(p, ...)
rm(p)
```

Effectively, the following `sed` command is used to preprocess the CSV input:

```
sed 's/\\"/""/g' file.csv
```

I don't call this beautiful, but at least you don't have to leave the R environment...

Answer (score 2):

My apologies ahead of time that this isn't more detailed -- I'm right in the middle of a code crunch.

You might consider using the scan() function. I created a simple sample file "sample.csv," which consists of:

```
V1,V2
"_:b5507F4C7x59005","Fabiana D\"atri"
```

Two quick possibilities are (with output commented so you can copy-paste to the command line):

```
test <- scan("sample.csv", sep=",", what='character',allowEscapes=TRUE)
## Read 4 items
test
##[1] "V1"                "V2"                "_:b5507F4C7x59005"
##[4] "Fabiana D\\atri\n"
```

or

```
test <- scan("sample.csv", sep=",", what='character',comment.char="\\")
## Read 4 items
test
## [1] "V1"                "V2"                "_:b5507F4C7x59005"
## [4] "Fabiana D\\atri\n"
```

You'll probably need to play around with it a little more to get what you want. And I see that you've already mentioned writeLines, so you may have already tried this. Either way, good luck!

Comment: `allowEscapes` is also an argument of `read.csv` and `read.table`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your eample to work by setting the `quote` argument:

```
> read.csv('test.csv',quote="'",head=FALSE)
                   V1                  V2
1 "_:b5507F4C7x59005" "Fabiana D\\"atri" 
2 "_:b5507F4C7x59005" "Fabiana D\\"atri"
```

Comment: I thought adding `allowEscapes=TRUE` might help but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: ...This kind of works unless there are single quotes in the file. But all strings end up with double-quotes around them (and the escaped quotes are still escaped), so some more processing is required...

Comment: As @Ben posted, the solution won't in my case. I have comma inside other fields.

Answer (score 1):

`read_delim` from package **readr** can handle escaped and doubled double quotes, using the arguments `escape_double` and `escape_backslash`.

For example, if our file escapes quotes by doubling them:

```
"quote""","hello"
1,2
```

then we use

```
read_delim(file, delim=',')  # default escape_backslash=FALSE, escape_double=TRUE
```

If our file escapes quotes with a backslash:

```
"quote\"","hello"
1,2
```

we use

```
read_delim(file, delim=',', escape_double=FALSE, escape_backslash=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of newer R versions, `readr::read_delim()` is the correct answer.

```
data = read_delim(filename, delim = "\t", quote = "\"",
    escape_backslash=T, escape_double=F,
    # The columns depend on your data
    col_names = c("timeStart", "posEnd", "added", "removed"),
    col_types = "nncc"
)
```

Answer (score -2):

This should be fine with `read.csv()`.  Take a look at the help for `?read.csv` - the option for specifying the quote is `quote = "...."`.  In this case, though, there may be a problem: it seems that `read.csv()` prefers to see matching quotes.

I tried the same with `read.table("sample.txt", header = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)`, with your text in `sample.txt`, and it seems to work.  When all else fails with `read.csv()`, I tend to back up to `read.table()` and specify the parameters carefully.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, try something slightly more complex, like: `writeLines(c("\"foo\",\"Fab D\\\"atri\",\"bar2\"","\"foo2\",\"Fab D\\\"atri2\",\"bar2\"" ), "foo.txt")`...

Comment: Keep in mind that your original output is, from R's perspective, just 1 string per line, rather than a bunch of separately quoted strings. If you want the entire thing quoted in a file, then you need surrounding quotes.

Comment: After `read.table`, I get `a$V2` outputs `[1] ",\"Fab" ",\"Fab"` which isn't correct. ...And if you open "foo.txt" in a text editor, you'll see that it contains strings like what the OP stated.