# R: Read in double-quote delimited CSV with extra double quote used instead of inch

Tags: r, csv

I have a double-quote delimited CSV file that has an extra double quote in it, `quotes.csv`

```
ID,Page,Category,Comments1
"6203168",26,"A","test, line 1"
"6205809",26,"B","test, line 2"
"6205410",16,"C","test, 3" line 3"
"6205410",16,"D","test, line 4"
```

I read a lot of SO and google links, but still cannot read the file correctly.
Basic code:

```
DataFrame = read.csv("quotes.csv",colClasses=c("character","integer","character","character"),header=TRUE,sep=",")
View(DataFrame)
```

I tried `quote="\""`, tried `read.table` with variations of `quote` - nothing helped. Note: It is not possible to manually edit the CSV file to correct that double quote. Looking for output like this:

```
    ID  Page    Category    Comments1
1   6203168 26  A   test, line 1
2   6205809 26  B   test, line 2
3   6205410 16  C   test, 3" line 3
4   6205410 16  D   test, line 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: The second to last line looks simply broken. There’s no good way to parse this unambiguously, you should sanitise your input data *before* handing it to R/`read.table`. It doesn’t have to be manual. But there’s no good general way of doing this, it requires quite intimate knowledge of what kinds of error/ambiguities can be expected in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066664/how-to-read-double-quote-escaped-values-with-read-table-in-r) Stack Overflow post, `read.csv` does not seem to be able to handle escaped double quotes.  But the link gives a possible workaround.  Most solutions I found involve removing the double quotes before calling `read.csv`.

In Linux, to remove all double quotes from a file called `input.csv`, use the `sed` command:

```
sed 's/\"//g' input.csv output.csv
```

Where `output.csv` is your csv file with all quotes having been stripped.

In Windows, removing quotes from a file is a bit hairier, and you would have to write a batch file.  However, there is an alternative.  When I was working with large `csv` files to do data modeling, I would just open the files in a program like `Textpad` or `Notepad++` and just do a global replace of all quotes.  You probably don't want this option if you are dealing with `csv` very often, but this alternative is just fine for occasional use.  Also note that when you open the `csv` file in an editor, you run the risk that the editor will save and/or strip special characters.

Comment: I read this question too. Did you remove them manually or auto?

Comment: Removing the double quotes manually would be time-consuming and error prone.

Comment: So how did you do it? SQL? Python? Can you, please, post your method?

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov Can you let us know whether you are running `R` on Windows or Linux, and what method you ended up using to remove double quotations from your csv file?

Comment: this time it's on x64 Win, and I haven't yet found the best way to do it. The problem gets more complicated as I work with strings and not always `"` there is used for inch, but users wrongly use it in e.g. `you"re`.