# fread can't read .csv file with escape "text 7\" text"

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I have a problem reading a big .csv file that contains some data in the form of "text 7\" text". For smaller files I just removed \" altogether, but the last one is over 500MB and I can't open it with Notepad ++ to replace the strings. An example row of actual data I can't read:

Unbranded/Generic,"15\", A1398",Does not apply,None,None,None,UK

Adding neither fill = TRUE nor quote = '' as arguments helps. Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066664/how-to-read-double-quote-escaped-values-with-read-table-in-r

Comment: data.table specific discussion here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109